# Trying to copy a formula down an entire column to the last row of data in an adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel

I am a new VBA user, and I am trying to create a VBA code to copy a single Vlookup formula down an entire column to the last row of data in an adjacent column. I don't want to specify a specific range, because I intend to use this macro with multiple different files that have different row ranges, so I am looking for a code that will simply copy down to the last value in an adjacent column.

I have tried looking at other similar questions and answers on this website, but none of the solutions that I have found have been working, and I would really appreciate some help!

Here is my code that I currently have:

```
' Section5 Macro
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(RC[6],'[PERSONAL.XLSB]Task and Sections'!R2C1:R254C2,2,FALSE)"
        Range("C2").Select
        Selection.Copy 'Copy Vlookup Formula

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("C3").AutoFill destination:=Range("C3:C" & lastRow) 'Specify range for Column C based off of row count in Column B

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False 'Paste Vlookup equation down the column
  End Sub
```

The formula I want to copy is "=VLOOKUP(RC[6],'[PERSONAL.XLSB]Task and Sections'!R2C1:R254C2,2,FALSE". The column that I want to copy this formula down is column C (in all rows except C1 which is the Header). The column that I want to refer to for row length is the adjacent column B.

Currently I am getting an error that says "Compile error: Named argument not found".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: For compile errors, look at the highlighted content. in this case, it is "desination". You mistyped. It is "destination". Feel free to delete the question, simple typos have no place on StackOverlow.

Comment: Even with that, the formula wasn't working. I have no need to delete the question when I have actually been trying to search for a solution for the past two days, and only reached out onto this forum because it seemed to have a positive, helpful community and I needed the help. At least I can tell the two users who had answers below are helpful and not making rude comments about "simple typos".

Comment: Well, being one of the users who have helped, I'm confused. :) Your question is about a Compile error. It is caused by a typographical error. We have rules on stack overflow saying these types of questions should be deleted. Not because we hate you, but because it likely won't benefit anyone in the future. I was not trying to be rude, I was trying to be helpful. Also, if an answer helped you, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: Well apologies for that confusion on my part. I will say that I think that my question was more about the formula, rather than simply that error since the code that I had posted was only one of five different versions of code that I had tried to create based off of different codes I had found on Stack Overflow and other sources online. Regardless, thank you for your help, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comment, you had a simple typo ("desination")... Nevertheless, your code doesn't seem to work even when this is fixed.
There's a much simpler approach. Try this:

```
Sub FillWithFormula()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C2:C" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=B2*2"
End Sub
```

Notice that I replaced your formula with a simpler one (independent of external data) so I could verify that the routine works.

Comment: Thanks, I will also try out this solution!! Noted about the formula--I will test it out for mine. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Remember that my solution uses A1-style formula

Answer (score 0):

Here.

```
Sub thing()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("C3:C" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[6],'[PERSONAL.XLSB]Task and Sections'!R2C1:R254C2,2,FALSE)"

    Range("C3:C" & lastRow).Value = Range("C3:C" & lastRow).Value
End Sub
```

Simpler, more elegant. Hasn't this kind of thing been solved like a million times all around the internet? Anyway, copy-paste is the slowest thing you can do in a macro. Avoid it. Just set the values of a range to be the values of the range. :)

Also, you can assign a formula to a whole range.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. Yeah, I found a bunch of different solutions online, but none of them seemed to be working with my code. Thank you again!!